# align link button below select box

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I am trying to position a link button below select box, but without success so far. All the time the link button is going right from the select box.
Below you can see the

```
 <div class="field">
 <select id="@("Select" +item.Name)" name="@("Select" +item.Name)"></select>  
 </div>
 <div class="removed">  
 <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
 </div>
```

And in the css I have only:

```
.field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}
```

How do you think I should approach this so the button will be below the select box.
Thanks in advance, LAziale

UPDATE: screenshot attached
[image: screenshot]

Html:

```
 <div id="accordion">

            @foreach (var item in Model.Parameters)
            {
                <h3><a href="#">@Html.LabelFor(m => item.Name, item.Prompt)</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="label">
                        Search @*Html.TextBox("Search")*@ 
                        <input id="@("Search" + item.Name)" type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("QuickSearch/" + item.Name, "Report")" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <select multiple id="@("Select" +item.Name)" name="@("Select" +item.Name)"></select>  

                    </div>
                    <div class="removed">  
                     <a href="#" class="remove">Remove selection</a>
                    </div>  

                </div>
            }         
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.display-label, 
.label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.display-field, 
.field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

.text-box {
    width: 30em;
}

.text-box.multi-line {
    height: 6.5em;
}

.tri-state {
    width: 6em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your code the link is coming down below the select box.

As you could see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/ninadajnikar/ZtNcx/

Or are you trying to do anything different here?

Comment: Can you pls share some more code of html and css as well, or else pls check if there are not any rules defined for removed and remove class in css file.

Comment: The updated code is giving me same output: link coming below the dropdown.....Can you try one thing close the first div inside the forerach loop before the removed class div or else just place a br tag before the removed class div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the clearfix? if no then try this

```
<div id="accordion">

            @foreach (var item in Model.Parameters)
            {
                <h3><a href="#">@Html.LabelFor(m => item.Name, item.Prompt)</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="label">
                        Search @*Html.TextBox("Search")*@ 
                        <input id="@("Search" + item.Name)" type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("QuickSearch/" + item.Name, "Report")" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <select multiple id="@("Select" +item.Name)" name="@("Select" +item.Name)"></select>  

                    </div>
                    <div class="CL"></div>   //Here is the change
                    <div class="removed">  
                     <a href="#" class="remove">Remove selection</a>
                    </div>  

                </div>
            }         
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.CL{ clear:both}
```

Comment: can you provide a link for this page?